# How do I loop this Google Apps Script function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to create a macro on Google sheets, which I did and it works perfectly, but I don't know how to get this function to loop.

```
function ba() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D8').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
  spreadsheet.getRange('F6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D10').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
  spreadsheet.getRange('G6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D12').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
  spreadsheet.getRange('D6:G6').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet9'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet8!D6:G6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet8'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D6:G14').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D14'));
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
};
```

Note: I tried to add the following snipet bellow the function, but it doesn't work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Logger.log(i);
}
```

Comment: I would advice you to follow some basic javascript tutorials . :)

Comment: @Calculuswhiz What I mean is to get the macro repeat the same action multiple times. Whenever the script finishes then it would run again. Thank you! :)

Comment: What did you try so far ? Did you Google for `how to create a loop` in Javascript? How many iterations do you want ?

Comment: @Marios Yes I tried. I read a few posts on different websites and I watched some videos on youtube aswell. But it's a little advanced for me as I am not a developer. I tried to add this code: `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Logger.log(i);
}` at the end of the function but it's not working.

Comment: @KhalidELBAZ You should add that snippet that you tried to your question.

Comment: Thank you @Calculuswhiz I did that, and it's working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to make this work. (Thank you @Calculuswhiz for the hint and everybody else for trying to help)

I added the following snippet at the end of the function:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Logger.log(i);
    }
```

I replaced `Logger.log(i);` With what I want to be repeated. Below is the final resualt

```
    function ba() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('E6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D8').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
      spreadsheet.getRange('F6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D10').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
      spreadsheet.getRange('G6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D12').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
      spreadsheet.getRange('D6:G6').activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet9'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('D6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet8!D6:G6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
      spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet8'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('D6:G14').activate();
      spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D14'));
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
      
      for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
      spreadsheet.getRange('E6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D8').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
      spreadsheet.getRange('F6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D10').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
      spreadsheet.getRange('G6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('D12').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
      spreadsheet.getRange('D6:G6').activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet9'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('D6').activate();
      spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet8!D6:G6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
      spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
      spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet8'), true);
      spreadsheet.getRange('D6:G14').activate();
      spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('D14'));
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
    }
    };
```